# ember.js template context w/connectOutlet

Tags: ember.js

When I do

```
var bob = App.MyModel.create().setProperties({ name: "bob marley" });
router.get('applicationController').connectOutlet('my', bob);
```

The instance of `MyModel` becomes the `content` property of the `MyController` instance. From what I read in the guide, the controller instance becomes the context for the handlebars template rendered by `MyView`.

Does that mean I always have to prefix the model's properties with `content.` in the templates?

```
<h1>{{content.name}}</h1>
```

is there something I'm missing or is this the correct way of doing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `App.MyController` extends `Ember.ObjectController`, then you should be able to use `{{name}}` directly. This is because `Ember.ObjectController` extends [`Ember.ObjectProxy`](http://docs.emberjs.com/#doc=Ember.ObjectProxy), rendering the `content` reference unnecessary.

If you're using `Ember.Controller`, however, you'll have to prefix the properties with `content.` like you said. For more details, see @trek's [controller documentation](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/tree/master/packages/ember-runtime/lib/controllers) that was recently committed.

Comment: You shouldn't use Ember.Controller directly though, better to use the 'concrete' classes = ObjectController or ArrayController.

Comment: Except for the case of your `App.ApplicationController` I suppose. I wonder if there will be a built-in `Ember.ApplicationController`?

Comment: @pauldechov what additional functionality would it provide over `Controller`?

Comment: I have no idea :-) it was just a thought. But it doesn't seem as "concrete" as those subclasses, as @RoyTruelove pointed out, though it's a distinct use of a controller and it is practically mandatory.

Comment: I guess what I was thinking of might be called a NavigationController rather, though I don't think the framework wants to get more specific than Arrays and Objects actually. In any case, I realized there could be other direct uses of `Ember.Controller` -- for content values that aren't Arrays or Objects, such as numbers and strings. A search string perhaps?